# oracle: populate a table from another schema using PL/sql procedure

Tags: oracle

hi i'm newb in pl/sql :), this is for educational pruposes only.
the schama **Dispatching** including a table named **Employes**.and **PRF** schema that include a table named **ZONE**.

**Dispatching : Employes(num_emp number,name nvarchar2,design_unit varchar2,design_zone varchar2)** 
 and **PRF: ZONE(num_zone number,design_zone varchar2,number_of_units number)**.
the problema is writing a pl/sql procedure to populate ZONE table from Employes table. this is my procedure :

```
create or replace procedure zoneD as

cursor   cur is select design_zone,design_unit from dispatching.employes group by design_zone,design_unit;  
varzone  cur%rowtype;



begin

open cur;

fetch cur into varzone;loop
exit when cur%notfound;

 insert into zone(num_zone,design_zone,nbr_of_unit) values (num_zone.nextval,varzone.design_zone,0);

 update zone set nbr_of_unit =( select count(design_unit) from dispatching.employes);

end loop;


close cur;


end zoneD;
```

the unit is a town , each zone contains many units. in a simple way the prob the procedure does not insert the data i dont know if it is the right way to do that. (sorry about my english :)).

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: i was late, i suppose th "e" is an object of employes table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are connected as PRF and want to fetch values that belong to  DISPATCHING user. In order to do that, DISPATCHING has to grant (at least) SELECT on its EMPLOYEES table to PRF:

```
-- connect as DISPATCHING
grant select on employees to prf;
```

A procedure (as you're practicing PL/SQL) should utilize a cursor FOR loop as it is much easier to maintain than a loop which uses explicitly declared cursor (as you don't need to declare it as well as variable(s) you need to store its values into), open it, worry when to exit the loop and - finally - close it. Cursor FOR loop does all of that for you (OK, except writing a SELECT statement which is just the same as the one you'd use while declaring an explicit cursor).

```
-- connect as PRF
create or replace procedure zoned as
begin
  -- cursor FOR loop - you can select both DESIGN_ZONE and count number of
  -- units so that you wouldn't have to update that value separately
  for cur_r in (select e.design_zone, count(*) number_of_units
                from dispatching.employees e  -- naming the owner which granted SELECT on its table to PRF user
                group by e.design_zone
               )
  loop
    insert into zone (num_zone, design_zone, number_of_units)
      values (num_zone.nextval, cur_r.design_zone, cur_r.number_of_units);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

That should do it (unless I made a typo).

Finally, a suggestion, if I may: do format your code properly. The one you posted is a mess difficult to read - no indentation, too long lines (break them!), and it contains only several lines. Imagine what happens when you have thousands of lines of code - who do you expect to debug it? Just a month or two after you've done with that code, you'll forget what you did and why (so comment it), and - if it is unformatted - you'll get a headache. Today's GUI tools offer automatic formatting, so - use it. Otherwise, there are free online formatters, such as [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

Comment: thank you sir i learn a lot from you , especialy about using control statements.

Comment: is it the "e" created with an "create type" ?

Comment: In this case `e` is what's called an "alias" for `EMPLOYEES`. Inside this query it can be used anywhere you'd normally use `EMPLOYEES` - so, as you can see, the person writing the query wrote `SELECT e.DESIGN_ZONE` instead of `SELECT EMPLOYEES.DESIGN_ZONE`. It's just a short way to refer to `EMPLOYEES`.

Comment: i understand , that the alias 'e' just its a pointer to employees table, i can use it  without any  pre-declaration , thank you Bob.

Comment: i want to populate PRF : unit_d(num_unit number,design_unit varchar2,nbr_employes number, num_zone) from zone table and employes table , the question is one cursor enugh ? i have to use join or a group by.

Comment: Yes, probably you can do it with one cursor whose SELECT is a JOIN between those two tables. I don't know whether you need a GROUP BY or not; it depends on what & how you SELECT (i.e. whether there's aggregation that requires GROUP BY clause).

Comment: i want to select design_unit  from employes , nbr_employes - numbers of employes per unit and num_zone from zone table.the condition is to associate eatch unit to its zone conform to employes table .asume that employes and zone are populated befor.

Comment: OK, so compose a SELECT statement and test whether it returns correct result in SQLPlus. When you make it work, just copy/paste it into a cursor FOR loop's *source* query. The rest is just the same - insert values you fetch from a cursor, don't forget to precede names with a cursor variable name ("cur_r" in my example).

Comment: SELECT e.designation_unite,
       Count(num_employe)NBR_EMPLOYES,
       d.num_zone -- jointure entre les tables employesd , zone_d
FROM   dispatching.employesd e
       FULL JOIN perf.zone_d d
              ON e.designation_zone = d.designation_zone
GROUP  BY e.designation_unite

Comment: sorry its in frensh version :D .

Comment: It seems that you have to GROUP BY D.NUM_ZONE as well.

Comment: sql dev show to me : ORA-00979:not a group by expression.

Comment: **Both** E.DESIGNATION_UNITE and D.NUM_ZONE should be part of the GROUP BY clause. ORA-00979 says so - all columns that aren't aggregated must be in GROUP BY.

Comment: i cant group by num_zone because the units are included in zone and each unit contain a number of employes. thank you Littlefoot

Comment: sorry  Littlefoot you have right :) , in grouping by num_zone and design_unit , it works very well thank you again.